# How to open new Activity for Vcard and how to open Google Maps app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am making a qr code scanner app and I can't complete two things. The first one is to pass information about `Vcard` to a new Activity. Here is the code I wrote:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    processRawResult(rawResult.getText());
}

private void processRawResult(String text){
    if (text.startsWith("BEGIN:")) {
        String[] tokens = text.split("\n");
        QRVcardModel qrVcardModel = new QRVcardModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if (tokens[i].startsWith("BEGIN:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setType(tokens[i].substring("BEGIN:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("N:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setName(tokens[i].substring("N:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("ORG:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setOrg(tokens[i].substring("ORG:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("TEL:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setTel(tokens[i].substring("TEL:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("URl:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setUrl(tokens[i].substring("URL:".length()));


            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("EMAIL:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setEmail(tokens[i].substring("EMAIL:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("ADR:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setAddress(tokens[i].substring("ADR:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("NOTE:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setNote(tokens[i].substring("NOTE:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("SUMMARY:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setSummary(tokens[i].substring("SUMMARY:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("DTSTART:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setDtstart(tokens[i].substring("DTSTART:".length()));

            } else if (tokens[i].startsWith("DTEND:")) {
                qrVcardModel.setDtend(tokens[i].substring("DTEND:".length()));

            }
        }

        Intent intentVcard = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VcardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentVcard);

    }
```

The second problem I face is that I can't open Google Maps app when I scan the `Geoqrcode`. Here is the code:

```
else if (text.startsWith("geo:"))
{
    QRGeoModel qrGeoModel = new QRGeoModel();
    String delims = "[ , ?q= ]+";
    String tokens[] = text.split(delims);

    for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
    {
        if (tokens[i].startsWith(" geo:"))
        {
            qrGeoModel.setLat(tokens[i].substring("geo:".length()));
        }
    }
    qrGeoModel.setLat(tokens[0].substring("geo:".length()));
    qrGeoModel.setLng(tokens[1]);
    qrGeoModel.setGeo_place(tokens[2]);

    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("qrGeoModel.getLat(),qrGeoModel.getLng()");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent);

}
```

Do you know how can I do that two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass values in Intent like this :

```
intentVcard.putExtra("value_name" , value);
```

value can be String, int, boolean, long and more (you can check in your ide what you can pass).

On the recieving activity you can get the value like this :

```
getIntent.getStrinExtra("value_name");
```

Be sure to replace it by your value name, for String it is like this, however for boolean it will be :

```
getIntent.getBooleanExtra("value_name" , defualt_value);
```

About the Google Maps problem, look at this line

```
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("qrGeoModel.getLat(),qrGeoModel.getLng()");
```

you don't need " there, that way you will pass it all as a string and not the actual value of qrGeoModel.getLat(), insted write this line like that :

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(qrGeoModel.getLat() + "," + qrGeoModel.getLng());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I scan a Geoqr code app crashes and stops. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: @IloveWeb Can you please show me the error it gives you?
You can see it on the Run window or the Log.

Comment: That is: `at com.androidcoding.qrcode.MainActivity.processRawResult(MainActivity.java:146)
        at com.androidcoding.qrcode.MainActivity.handleResult(MainActivity.java:72)
        at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView$1.run(ZXingScannerView.java:164)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)`